# Mean Value Property, Dirichlet problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $\mathcal{B}_1 (0) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $u \in C^2 (\mathcal{B}_1(0)) \cap C(\overline{\mathcal{B}_1 (0)})$ the solution of the dirichlet-problem
$$- \Delta u=0 \mbox{ in } \mathcal{B}_1 (0)$$
$$u(x)= x*e_1 \mbox{ on } \partial\mathcal{B}_1 (0)$$
with $e_1=(1,0,...0)$. Determine the value of $u(0)$ without calculating.

With the Mean Value Property I get $ u(0)= \frac{1}{|\partial \mathcal{B}_r (0)|} \int_{\partial \mathcal{B}_r (0)} u(y) dS(y)$ for $0<r<1$.

So $u(0)= \lim_{r\rightarrow 1} \frac{1}{|\partial \mathcal{B}_r (0)|} \int_{\partial \mathcal{B}_r (0)} u(y) dS(y)$

I'm not sure if i can set the right side $= \frac{1}{|\partial \mathcal{B}_1 (0)|} \int_{\partial \mathcal{B}_1 (0)}y_1 dS(y)$ and how i calculate this integral, it is clear that it is smaller than 1.

Comment: Hint: The boundary condition $u(x)=x_1$ is an odd function on $\partial B_1(0)$. You can find the value of the integral without any computation.

Comment: I know for a odd  function is the integral over a symmetric intervall 0. But here i have a much more difficult situation. Maybe can help cavaleri?